# Cabal with multiple Library sections

Tags: haskell, build, cabal, build-system

Is it possbile to write a `Cabal` configuration file, which contains multiple `Library sections`?

I found in [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#library) the description of Library **section** and Executables **sections**, so it seems, that it is impossible to put more Library section in one Cabal configuration file.

But what should I do if I'm developing several Haskell libraries and several executables
simultaneously and want to compile and test them all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out, that my problem can be easly solved with the newest [cabal-dev](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev/blob/master/README.md).

If you've got 2 projects: `A` and `B` and you want to develop them in parallel, its nice to use `cabal-dev install A B` - it will build and install them both to the local `cabal-dev` repository. If you **re-run** this command, they will be rebuilt and reinstalled if necessary.

According to the documentation - If you want to **register new** or **override existing** package on **local cabal-dev hackage**, you should use `cabal-dev add-source`, which basically copy the source and allows you to install it like it was available on `hackage`.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, you can't put more than one library in a cabal file. The name specified in the `Name` field (at the top level of the cabal file) is used as the name of the library, so there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for specifying names of additional libraries.

In practice, I haven't found this to be a problem. I develop each library in a separate directory, with its own cabal file. Once you run `cabal install` on a library you've developed, then it can be referenced in the cabal file for your executable (in the `Build-Depends` section), just the same as a package on Hackage.

So, for example, if you have two libraries with cabal files that look like this:

```
Name:              my-library-1
. . .
```

and

```
Name:              my-library-2
. . .
```

Then the cabal file for your executable can reference them like this:

```
Name:              my-program
. . .
Executable run-program
Main-Is:          Main.hs
Build-Depends:    my-library1,
                  my-library2,
                  . . .
```

You can even require specific versions of your libraries. For example:

```
Build-Depends:    my-library1==1.2.*,
                  my-library2>=1.3
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I can use it like this, but I wanted to simplify ther process of developing multiple libraries at once - and building and reinstalling them all the time, but it seems that `cabal-dev` solves my problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you could do that sort of thing with `cabal-dev`. You might want to describe how you did it, post that as an answer here, and then accept it. Others may be interested in the solution.

Comment: @mhwombad - see below :)

Answer (score 7):

This is possible in Cabal 2 with internal libraries, so called "convenience" libraries: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/3022. This will not let you install these libraries though, they are just allowed to be composed into the final executables and public library exposed by a `.cabal` file. If you want to build multiple things in progress, you should use a `cabal.project` file - http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/ has some information on this.